# Any depth nested dict to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, nested

I've been fighting to go from a nested dictionary of depth *D* to a pandas DataFrame.

I've tried with recursive function, like the following one, but my problem is that when I'm iterating over a KEY, I don't know what was the pervious key.

I've also tried with json.normalize, pandas from dict but I always end up with dots in the columns...

Example code:

```
def iterate_dict(d, i = 2, cols = []):
    
    for k, v in d.items():
        # missing here how to check for the previous key
        # so that I can create an structure to create the dataframe.
        if type(v) is dict:   
            print('this is k: ', k)  
            if i % 2  == 0:
                cols.append(k)
            i+=1
            iterate_dict(v, i, cols)            
        else:
            print('this is k2: ' , k, ': ', v)

  
iterate_dict(test2)
```

This is an example of how my dictionary looks like:

```
# example 2 
test = {
    'column-gender': {
        'male': {
            'column-country' : {
                'FRENCH': {
                    'column-class': [0,1]
                },
                ('SPAIN','ITALY') : {
                    'column-married' : {
                        'YES': {
                            'column-class' : [0,1]
                        },
                        'NO' : {
                            'column-class' : 2
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        'female': {
            'column-country' : {
                ('FRENCH', 'SPAIN') : {
                    'column-class' : [[1,2],'#']
                },
                'REST-OF-VALUES': {
                    'column-married' : '*'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I want the dataframe to look like:

[image]

Any suggestion is welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column-keys are consistently prefixed with `column-`, you can create a recursive function:

```
def data_to_df(data):
    rec_out = []
    def dict_to_rec(d, curr_row={}):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if 'column-' in k: # definition of a column
                if isinstance(v, dict):
                    for val, nested_dict in v.items():
                        dict_to_rec(nested_dict, dict(curr_row, **{k[7:]: val}))
                else:
                    rec_out.append(dict(curr_row, **{k[7:]: v}))
    dict_to_rec(data)
    return pd.DataFrame(rec_out)

print(data_to_df(test))
```

Edit: removing unnecessary variable and argument

Output:

```
   gender          country        class married
0    male           FRENCH       [0, 1]     NaN
1    male   (SPAIN, ITALY)          YES  [0, 1]
2    male   (SPAIN, ITALY)           NO       2
3  female  (FRENCH, SPAIN)  [[1, 2], #]     NaN
4  female   REST-OF-VALUES            *     NaN
```

Comment: Impressive! @Tranbi Thanks so much. For now, I will try to figure out what does the "**", never seen it, (only in C++)!

Comment: `dict(d1, **d2)` allows to combine two dictionaries without altering any of them. In our case `curr_out` should stay unchanged during the loop. The `**` operator unpacks a dictionary in key/value pairs (similar to `*` on lists). So if `d2={k:v}`, it is equivalent to `dict(d1, k=v)` which would be also valid. However since `columns[depth]` must be interpreted before being passed as argument, we build the dict first and unpack it.

Comment: BTW I just noticed that `columns` and `depth` are not needed. (I was probably going for something slightly different when I started, besides it was the end of the day ^^') Editing my code right away...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how that data going to be consistent but for just understanding we can do something like the below, remember this is just a little demo on the approach of how we can handle it, you can spend more time to polish it up accordingly:

I added comments on each step for better understanding.

```
import pandas as pd


def nested_dict_to_df(data, columns=None):

    if columns are None:
        columns = []

    # if the data is a dictionary, then we need to iterate over the keys
    if isinstance(data, dict):

        for key, value in data.items():
            columns.append(key)
            yield from nested_dict_to_df(value, columns)  # recursive call
            columns.pop()  # remove the last element
    else:
        yield columns + [data]


df = pd.DataFrame(nested_dict_to_df(data))

# Drop column [0, 2, 4, 6] from the dataframe that are not needed for the final output
df = df.drop(df.columns[[0, 2, 4, 6]], axis=1)

header = ["GENDER", "COUNTRY", "CLASS", "MARRIED"]  # Desired header
df.columns = header

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   GENDER          COUNTRY        CLASS MARRIED
0    male           FRENCH       [0, 1]    None
1    male   (SPAIN, ITALY)          YES  [0, 1]
2    male   (SPAIN, ITALY)           NO       2
3  female  (FRENCH, SPAIN)  [[1, 2], #]    None
4  female   REST-OF-VALUES            *    None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `NestedDict` from the open-source [`ndicts`](https://github.com/edd313/ndicts) package (I am the author).

```
>>> from ndicts import NestedDict
>>> nd = NestedDict(test)
```

Get all the items in the `NestedDict` and flatten the keys to form the lines of the `DataFrame`.

```
>>> data = [[*key, value] for key, value in nd.items()]
[['column-gender', 'male', 'column-country', 'FRENCH', 'column-class', [0, 1]], 
 ...
]
```

Initialize the `DataFrame` and drop the unwanted columns.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = (
        pd.DataFrame(data)
        .drop(columns=[0, 2, 4, 6])
    )
```

Finally, rename the columns.

```
>>> df.columns = ["GENDER", "COUNTRY", "CLASS", "MARRIED"]
>>> df
   GENDER          COUNTRY        CLASS MARRIED
0    male           FRENCH       [0, 1]    None
1    male   (SPAIN, ITALY)          YES  [0, 1]
2    male   (SPAIN, ITALY)           NO       2
3  female  (FRENCH, SPAIN)  [[1, 2], #]    None
4  female   REST-OF-VALUES            *    None
```